# Is "willfully disingenuous" a tautologism?

Tags: meaning, adjectives, semantics

It seems to me that definitions of disingenuous such as the following might imply willfulness:

> adjective
>
> 1. lacking in frankness, candour, or sincerity; falsely or hypocritically ingenuous; >insincere: 
>      "Her excuse was rather disingenuous."

Is the adjective necessary?

Comment: Hey James -- I believe, you did not mean "tautologism" but rather "redundant"

Comment: Oxford Dictionaries (not same thing as OED) does not list 'tautologism'. The word I think you need is *tautology*. *Tautological, tautologise, tautologist, tautologize, and tautologous* are all there but not 'tautologism'!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like many phrases which, from a logical, let's-treat-English-as-algebra perspective, are redundant (not *tautological*), "willfully disingenuous" is, from a *linguistic* perspective,  merely **emphatic** (adding emphasis, underscoring, making sharper or clearer ... sorry, I'm being redundant here ).

In other words, "*willful*" here isn't being used to mean "*intentional*", it's being used to mean "***stubbornly***" or "***obstinately***".

Comment: I was wondering if that would be the opinion. Perhaps you won't be surprised to know I am a programmer. :)

Comment: Also, it's good to see redundant vs. tautology clarified here. I searched a lot but couldn't find clarity on whether tautology was an applicable term this situation. It seems it's used a lot for redundant adjectives.

Comment: James, no problem. If you're hiring me to be pedantic, I'm going to be *pedantic* ;)

Comment: I would have typed basically the identical answer word for word!  :)

Comment: WS - nah, you can emphasis the "wilful" part of the disenguousness. (Consider the expression "hmm, a wilful child...")  You could also emphasise other parts of the disingenuousness.  Harsh disingenuousness, careless disingenuousness, stupid disingenuousness, repeated disingenuousness, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that it is possible to be passively or generally disingenuous (i.e. by default), but wilfully disingenuous when you are really trying...

Answer (score 0):

Can one be 'wilfully aggressive'? I suppose some people are just made that way, so there is no need for an effort of will. Could it be like that with *disingenuity*?

I would certainly agree with what @Dan Bron says, but the other question would be whether it were possible to be *disingenuous* without being *wilful* (spelled with one l in Britain).

Given that one meaning of *wilful* is 'intentional; deliberate', one has to consider the matter carefully.

But I had a colleague who once said to a particularly irate customer, 'Are you deliberately insulting me or just doing it by accident?'

It must be possible to convey *disingenuity* casually, or just be the kind of person who does it without thinking.

So, in short, I do not think there is an adjectival redundancy!

Answer (score -1):

I think the actual tautology lies with the *actual word*, "disingenuous".

I may well be displaying my etymological ignorance here, but surely:

– "Genuine" – opposite of "genuous";
– "Ingenuous" – opposite of "genuous" – therefore, why not just say,
"genuine"?
– "disingenuous" – is this not, effectively, the same as saying "genuous"?

Yet, the last time I checked my *Concise Oxford Dictionary* – and my *Collins Scrabble Dictionary* – neither of them list "genuous" as a word.

But I think this word *ought* to be. (I'm clearly missing something...)

I submit this answer with some trepidation – knowing that someone who is far better qualified will shortly shoot down my argument!

Comment: At the moment, your answer lacks support for its key statements ("Genuine" – opposite of "genuous" – "Ingenuous" – opposite of "genuous") because you don't have an authoritative definition for "genuous". You might be in a flammable/inflammable situation where the words aren't opposites.

Comment: [Ingenuous](https://www.etymonline.com/word/ingenuous) originally referred to someone who was born in a place (prefix *in-* meaning "in"), later passing through various shifts in meaning, as any reference book will tell you. It's not the opposite of *genuous*.